# Grunt: style: 'compressed' VS cssmin

Tags: sass, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-cssmin

I am quite new to Grunt and I am wondering why one should use grunt-contrib-cssmin instead of creating dev/dist versions like in this example:

```
    sass: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                style: 'compressed',
            },
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'assets/styles/source',
                src: [
                    '*.scss'
                ],
                dest: 'assets/styles/build',
                ext: '.min.css'
            }]
        },
        dev: {
            options: {
                style: 'extended',
            },
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'assets/styles/source',
                src: [
                    '*.scss'
                ],
                dest: 'assets/styles/build',
                ext: '.css'
            }]
        }           
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The compress option of Sass does, see also http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#_16:

> Compressed style takes up the minimum amount of space possible, having
>   no whitespace except that necessary to separate selectors and a
>   newline at the end of the file. It also includes some other minor
>   compressions, such as choosing the smallest representation for colors.
>   It’s not meant to be human-readable.

grunt-contribe-cssmin uses [clean-css](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css) to compress AND optimize your CSS. Optimizations which Clean-css does, and Sass compress not are among others: selector & property merging,   reduction, etc. (advanced optimizations), properties merging based on their order, @media` merging, restructuring optimizations and shorthand compacting